# Chrome Driver Autodownload is not working for chrome version 115 and above

Tags: appium-android

We were using -> "--allow-insecure","chromedriver_autodownload" this piece of code to autodownload the chrome driver in our android automation using appium , but with the latest release of chrome having version 115 , we are unable to download the chromedriver v115, its always downloading v114, and automation is failing since the chrome browser and webview implementation version got upgraded to 115, any idea how to make that autodownload code work, or we have to manually download the chrome driver as per the version.

Any suggestions would help on how to make this thing work

Answer (score 0):

This is because the web driver 115 is not available on the official website- https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

However, they've rolled it out for testing purposes at: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

Direct download for Windows-
https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/115.0.5790.170/mac-arm64/chromedriver-mac-arm64.zip

As per their website: If you are using Chrome version 115 or newer, please consult the [Chrome for Testing availability dashboard](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/). This page provides convenient JSON endpoints for specific ChromeDriver version downloading.